# String encoding with a JSON flow got by web request C#

Tags: c#, json, string, encoding

I have a little problem with a string in C#. Actually, I take a JSON flow by an URL.

```
WebClient webC   = new WebClient();
string jsonStr = webC.DownloadString("http://www.express-board.fr/api/jobs");
```

But when I write the string in the console, I have the problem of encoding.

```
[...]"contract":"Freelance/IndÃ©pendant"[...]
```

I have try to used lot of trick seen on stackoverflow with Encoding class. But impossible, to solve the problem. Of course if I use the link directly in my web browser and open it in Notepadd++ no problem.

Sometimes, with some combinaison of encoding ( ACSII-> UTF-8 I think), I obtain this :

```
[...]"contract":"Freelance/IndÃ©pendant"[...] to 
[...]"contract":"Freelance/Ind??pendant"[...]
```

Comment: What web server is involved? It sounds like it's advertising the wrong encoding. If it's under your control, the right solution is to fix that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This actually returns the string as intended:

```
WebClient webC = new WebClient();
webC.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
string jsonStr = webC.DownloadString("http://www.express-board.fr/api/jobs");
```